# How does phase relate to motions in an image?

Tags: filters, computer-vision, image-processing, phase

There is lots of research based on exaggerating motions by decomposing an image into complex sub-bands using pyramid representations such as the complex steerable pyramid and manipulating phase signals to amplify motions. This avoids the estimation of optical flow

Examples:

[1] http://people.csail.mit.edu/nwadhwa/phase-video/

[2] https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-49409-8_8

I am interested in this research. I don't have an image processing background. My question is how does phase relate to motion in an image? Why does manipulating phase not affect colors in an image?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.se Osama Qarem! This well-known paper on "The importance of phase in signals" might interest you: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1456290.

Comment: Very useful paper. Thank you. From what I understand now and put very simply, phase contains information about the location of features within an image. Regarding colors, I should have read the research more carefully. The reason it does not affect colors because for the specific algorithm I am asking about, is because the processing is done in YUV color space on the Luminance "Y" channel only, as processing the other channels is not needed.